# Error when trying to retrieve data from a table using ExecuteScalar<object>?

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this class:

```
public class BtnCountViews
{
    public int btnCount { get; set; }
    public int views { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to retrieve data for one row from my database:

```
sql = " AVG (BTNACOUNT + BTNBCOUNT) AS btnCount, AVG (VIEWS) As views ";
var avg = db2.ExecuteScalar<BtnCountViews>("SELECT " + sql + " FROM CLICKHISTORY");
```

But this is throwing an exception saying:

```
System.NotSupportedException: Don't know how to read Japanese.BtnCountViews
at SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ReadCol (SQLitePCL.sqlite3_stmt stmt,
```

I tried to look into ExecuteScalar and it seems like it can take an object.

Does anyone have any idea why it could be throwing an exception?

For reference here's the object definition for the CLICKHISTORY table:

```
public class ClickHistory
{
    [PrimaryKey, NotNull]
    public string Yymmdd { get; set; }
    public int DayOfYear { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public int Month { get; set; }
    public int Day { get; set; }
    public int BtnACount { get; set; }
    public int BtnBCount { get; set; }
    public int BtnCCount { get; set; }
    public int BtnDCount { get; set; }
    public int Views { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to return a type of `BtnCountViews` , not a scalar value.

Either return the projected `BtnCountViews` via a `Query`:

```
var sql = "AVG (BTNACOUNT + BTNBCOUNT) AS btnCount, AVG (VIEWS) As views ";
var avg = conn.Query<BtnCountViews>("SELECT " + sql + " FROM CLICKHISTORY").First();

Log.Debug(TAG, $"{avg.btnCount} : {avg.views}");
```

Or bring back the scalars in two separate queries via `ExecuteScalar`:

```
var sql2 = "(AVG (BTNACOUNT + BTNBCOUNT))";
var btnABAvg = conn.ExecuteScalar<int>("SELECT " + sql2 + " FROM CLICKHISTORY");

var sql3 = "(AVG (VIEWS))";
var viewAvg = conn.ExecuteScalar<int>("SELECT " + sql3 + " FROM CLICKHISTORY");

Log.Debug(TAG, $"{btnABAvg} : {viewAvg}");
```